# How to make the layout consistent in different devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I'm having a problem in the appearance of the layout in 2 different devices. I have included drawables of different sizes, but the layout looks strange in 1 device.

I have attached images to understand how the layout varies.

For HTC Sensation XE, OS 4.0.3, 4.3 inch QHD resolution the layout appears to be ok.

[image: Layout For HTC Sensation]

For Galaxy S4, OS 4.3, the last 4 EditTexts seem to be blank.
[image: Layout for Galaxy S4]

Here is the XML code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_recipient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/text_recipient"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addr1_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addr2_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/city_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/state_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/postcode_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/country_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/btn_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_save_iphone" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_cancel_iphone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_contacts"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_recipient"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_save"
    android:text="@string/addr_book" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please guide as I am a beginner in Android programming.

Comment: You didn't specify a style or a background for the four bottom EditTexts, so they are taking whatever the activity's theme defines. Do you have multiple style XML files in different folders, such as `values` and `values-xhdpi`? Maybe you set a style in one of these for edit text backgrounds, but not the other.

Comment: try setting `android:background="@null"` on the misbehaving EditText views.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have specified a background for the RelativeLayout (Rlayout_recipient) which holds all the Editexts android:background="@drawable/bg". I do not have any XML style files in different folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a background for the EditTexts, they will use a default from the theme. If you aren't using a Holo theme, then the device's default theme can be unpredictable, because all the device manufacturers like to reskin the default themes in various ways.

If you want them to have invisible backgrounds on all devices, set `android:background="@null"` or `android:background="#00000000"` on them.

Notice in your top pic the bottom edit texts are showing a thin underline from that device's default theme. Explicitly setting a null or invisible background will ensure that it is the same regardless of the theme. Or you can set your theme to Holo or some descendent of Holo, since it is the only theme that is guaranteed to be the same on all devices (no manufacturer reskins).

If you want to support devices older than Honeycomb, and therefore cannot use Holo on older devices, you need to specify a theme and enforce text colors and backgrounds as necessary. An easy way to do this would be to use [this site](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate a theme for you, and then edit that as necessary. That will ensure all bases are covered.

Comment: So now I have set android:background="@null" for those last 4 EditTexts and those lines below each EditText has disappeared..does this also solve the white band problem (showing in Galaxy S4)? I still have to do some testing in S4. I'm not supporting devices older than HoneyComb.

Comment: It should as long as something else isn't going wrong as well.